# Power BI Desktop - PostgreSQL : Unable to connect

Tags: postgresql, windows, powerbi, connection, digital-ocean

Im triying to connect a PostgreSQL database (only read node) hosted in Digital Ocean.
*The problem is the connection to power bi; because i was able to connect the database in pgAdmin4 for example.
The only difference in the connection is that in pgAdmin4 i was able to specify the `SSL: required`, but not in Power BI, but i think that is not the reason.

Server example: `my-postgres-analytics-do-user-420-0.b.db.ondigitalocean.com`
Database example: `pool`

I am getting the following error in power bi:

[Unable to connect Power BI - image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3sDXq.png)
`Details: "An error happened while reading data from the provider: 'A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond'"`

What i did: try to connect power bi to postgresql database
What i expect: connect power bi to postgresql database

Comment: Is powerBI desktop running on the same machine as the successful pgadmin4 is running on?

Comment: hey @jannes, yes same machine